# Looping through the xml and read all child node values using vbscript

Tags: xml, vbscript, xml-parsing

I'm fairly new to VB Scripting and trying to read the xml by parsing through each block of attributes in the xml response. I did see other posts with examples but couldn't find anything straight forward that helped with this problem here. The xml structures in other posts were different and hence this is not a duplicate question. Below is the code i started and could get until getting the num of nodes but couldn't read the values..

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmlDoc.load "C:\TestData\Blhdr_sampleresp_test.xml"
Set objNodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Blhd_cust_head_detail")
If objNodeList.length > 0 then
    For each x in objNodeList
                    ' The below code line works but I would like to be able get the value of specified node
        Set objNode = objXMLDoc.documentElement.lastChild
        Print objNode.text
        'blhdnum=x.getAttribute("Blhd_cust_head_nb")
        'Print blhdnum
    Next
Else
    Print " No child nodes  found."
End If
```

Here's the sample xml i have:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetBillCustResponse xmlns="http://www.test.com/test3">
         <GetBillCustResult>
            <Blhd_request>
               <User_id>User1</User_id>
               <Origin_sys_nm>TEST</Origin_sys_nm>
               <Operation_nm>GETCUST</Operation_nm>
               <Blhd_rqst_data>
                  <Blhd_cust_acct_nb>0755970501</Blhd_cust_acct_nb>
                  <Blhd_cust_start_dt>2019-09-10</Blhd_cust_start_dt>
                  <Blhd_cust_stop_dt>2019-12-12</Blhd_cust_stop_dt>
               </Blhd_rqst_data>
            </Blhd_request>
            <Blhd_return>
               <Response_cd>20000</Response_cd>
               <Response_desc_tx>SUCCESS</Response_desc_tx>
               <Err_cnt>0</Err_cnt>
               <Error_details/>
               <Blhd_resp_data>
                  <Blhd_cust_head_cnt>2</Blhd_cust_head_cnt>
                  <Blhd_cust_head_detail>
                     <Blhd_cust_head_nb>102</Blhd_cust_head_nb>
                     <Blhd_cust_dt>2019-11-11</Blhd_cust_dt>
                  </Blhd_cust_head_detail>
                  <Blhd_cust_head_detail>
                     <Blhd_cust_head_nb>104</Blhd_cust_head_nb>
                     <Blhd_cust_dt>2019-12-12</Blhd_cust_dt>
                  </Blhd_cust_head_detail>
               </Blhd_resp_data>
            </Blhd_return>
         </GetBillCustResult>
      </GetBillCustResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked for me for an xml that had a structure like this.

```
strFileName = "C:\TestData\Blhdr_sampleresp_test.xml"
Set objDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
objDoc.Async = False
objDoc.Load strFileName

'Get all the orderlist nodes

Set objNodeList = objDoc.SelectNodes("//Blhd_cust_head_detail")
Print objNodeList.length

'Loop through each of the returned nodes in the nodelist

 For Each objNode In objNodeList
    Set objSubNode = objNode.SelectSingleNode("Blhd_cust_head_nb")
    Print objSubNode.Text

    Set objSubNode = objNode.SelectSingleNode("Blhd_cust_dt")
    Print objSubNode.Text
Next

'Cleanup

Set objNodeList = Nothing
Set objDoc = Nothing
```